# Change html table cell color depending on its value

Tags: php, html

Hi i am trying to change the colors of a html table depending on values i read from a database. I am sending an image of what i m trying to achieve.
[image: table]

Comment: you need to share the code that you're trying so far. StackOverflow isn't a place to have people code for you, but rather a place for us to help you figure out where things aren't working in code you already have.

Comment: Please provide some information, not just "this is what I want to do". Show your code, tell us what the conditions are for changing the colours, tell use what you have tried, and crucially *ask an actual question*. You are not a new user so you should know what is expected of you. We are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: Yea there is no code about that object yet :), i was thinking about using RGB with one of them variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I think you received the downvote because your post is really lacking in detail (you should try to provide some code example for what you have tried so far).

I'm going to assume you're using PHP to render the HTML and that you want to apply a different tint of orange based upon the value where a value of "0" is white and a value of, say, "30" is full orange. I haven't tested the code here and no doubt you'll need to modify it to work with your specific code - as I don't know what data is available.

```
$max = 30;
$values = array( 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 );
$white = array(255, 255, 255);
$orange = array(255, 63, 0);

echo '<table><tr>';
foreach ( $values as $value ) {
    $red = $white[ 0 ] + ( ( $orange[ 0 ] - $white[ 0 ] ) * $value / $max );
    $green = $white[ 1 ] + ( ( $orange[ 1 ] - $white[ 1 ] ) * $value / $max );
    $blue = $white[ 2 ] + ( ( $orange[ 2 ] - $white[ 2 ] ) * $value / $max );

    $color = $rgb2html( $red, $green, $blue );

    echo '<td style="background-color: '.$color.'">'.$value.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';

// function from http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_convert_rgb_from_to_html_hex_color.xml
function rgb2html($r, $g=-1, $b=-1)
{
    if (is_array($r) && sizeof($r) == 3)
        list($r, $g, $b) = $r;

    $r = intval($r); $g = intval($g);
    $b = intval($b);

    $r = dechex($r<0?0:($r>255?255:$r));
    $g = dechex($g<0?0:($g>255?255:$g));
    $b = dechex($b<0?0:($b>255?255:$b));

    $color = (strlen($r) < 2?'0':'').$r;
    $color .= (strlen($g) < 2?'0':'').$g;
    $color .= (strlen($b) < 2?'0':'').$b;
    return '#'.$color;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i know i should post code, but the one so far isnt worth posting it just changes the RED and the final color moves weirdly between red and black but that looks better i will check it out.

Comment: I ended up using this for everyone interested
[link](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-79463.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle that.

1. You render your cells with a specific class on each range of value with if & else statements. Bit complicated.

2.You render your complete table, and then read each values with javascript and change background color on purpose.

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the OP has put so little effort in. Encouraging them just makes the problem worse...